# After "," in array set <br />

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have:

```
var a = ['bla bla bla', 'bla bla', 'bla']
```

and would like when I display this HTML, after every `,` to be new line (`<br />`), but I do not know how to do this. I tried this:

```
var a = ['bla bla bla', 'bla, bla', 'bla']
{a.map(b => {
  return b + <br />   //but this getting error .... whitout <br /> don't get error but doesn't have new line
})
}
```

I do not know how long array `a` will be, because of this I did not do:

```
{a[0] } 
<br /> 
{a[1]} 
<br />
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: `a.join("<br/>")`

Comment: "but this getting error"... What's the error? Search for the error text and you may find your answer faster.

Comment: THis might be your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69485336/8555837

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return a JSX Element:

```
a.map(b => {
  return <>{b}<br /></>
});
```

You need the `<>` and `</>` since you can only return a single value. More on fragments [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `map` here. Try `join` instead.

```js
const fullString = a.join('<br/>')
```

Though, it's really unclear how you are outputting this.

Comment: a.map(b => {
  return <>{b}<br /></>
})

Comment: i am dump i just need to do that

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding `"<br />"`, I recommend to use built in JSON functions:

```js
var a = ['bla bla bla', 'bla, bla', 'bla'];
a = JSON.stringify(a, null, 4)
document.getElementById("output").innerText = a
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```